# Inserting two rows that are almost identical to each other

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I'm trying to make test data for an application I'm writing, and some of my test data is very repetitive, involving inserting a row and then inserting another row that is identical except for one column. As such, I have very repetitive INSERT statements that make the file longer than I think it needs to be.

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[InvoiceItem] (invoice_item_name, amount, invoice_id) VALUES
  ('TUITION',
    (SELECT tuition_amount FROM [dbo].[Grade] WHERE grade_id = 
      (SELECT grade_id FROM [dbo].[Student] WHERE first_name = 'Murdoch')),
    (SELECT invoice_id FROM [dbo].[Invoice] WHERE student_id =
      (SELECT student_id FROM [dbo].[Student] WHERE first_name = 'Murdoch' AND invoice_date = '2019-09-05'))),
  ('TUITION_SERVICE_FEE',
    (SELECT tuition_amount FROM [dbo].[Grade] WHERE grade_id = 
      (SELECT grade_id FROM [dbo].[Student] WHERE first_name = 'Murdoch')) * 0.03,
    (SELECT invoice_id FROM [dbo].[Invoice] WHERE student_id =
      (SELECT student_id FROM [dbo].[Student] WHERE first_name = 'Murdoch' AND invoice_date = '2019-09-05'))),
  ('TUITION',
    (SELECT tuition_amount FROM [dbo].[Grade] WHERE grade_id = 
      (SELECT grade_id FROM [dbo].[Student] WHERE first_name = 'Hartwell')),
    (SELECT invoice_id FROM [dbo].[Invoice] WHERE student_id =
      (SELECT student_id FROM [dbo].[Student] WHERE first_name = 'Hartwell' AND invoice_date = '2019-09-05'))),
  ('TUITION_SERVICE_FEE',
    (SELECT tuition_amount FROM [dbo].[Grade] WHERE grade_id = 
      (SELECT grade_id FROM [dbo].[Student] WHERE first_name = 'Hartwell')) * 0.03,
    (SELECT invoice_id FROM [dbo].[Invoice] WHERE student_id =
      (SELECT student_id FROM [dbo].[Student] WHERE first_name = 'Hartwell' AND invoice_date = '2019-09-05'))),
```

Is there a way to clean this up by any chance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create a Stored Procedure that does this with a parameter called `@firstname`

it would come out way cleaner.

here is what the create would look like, I added in the `@InvoiceDate` parameters as well thinking that it was also something that was not static in the insert statement.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Sproc_Name   
    @FirstName nvarchar(50)
    ,@InvoiceDate DateTime
AS   
INSERT INTO [dbo].[InvoiceItem] (invoice_item_name, amount, invoice_id) VALUES
('TUITION',
    (SELECT tuition_amount FROM [dbo].[Grade] WHERE grade_id = 
    (SELECT grade_id FROM [dbo].[Student] WHERE first_name = @FirstName)),
    (SELECT invoice_id FROM [dbo].[Invoice] WHERE student_id =
    (SELECT student_id FROM [dbo].[Student] WHERE first_name = @FirstName AND invoice_date = @InvoiceDate))),
('TUITION_SERVICE_FEE',
    (SELECT tuition_amount FROM [dbo].[Grade] WHERE grade_id = 
    (SELECT grade_id FROM [dbo].[Student] WHERE first_name = @FirstName)) * 0.03,
    (SELECT invoice_id FROM [dbo].[Invoice] WHERE student_id =
    (SELECT student_id FROM [dbo].[Student] WHERE first_name = @FirstName AND invoice_date = @InvoiceDate)))   
GO
```

and then you would call it like this

```
EXECUTE Sproc_Name @FirstName = "Murdoch", @InvoiceDate = CONVERT(date, GETDATE())
-- CONVERT(date, GETDATE()) gives you 2018-04-05
```

I just used `GetDate()` for illustrative purposes, you can put in a string like `"2018-04-05"` and it should work as well.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to insert all of the invoice items for all students with an invoice date of '2019-09-05'?  If you use a single query to get all the students you are interested in creating invoice items for, then in the end you would have a total of two insert statements.  The one below, then a similar one for the 'Tuition_Service_Fee'.  Also, using table joins instead of sub queries is preferred in my opinion - more readable and can be better performing.  But definitely, use variables instead of hardcoded values will allow the code to be reused whether you just call the script or create a stored procedure.

```
declare @invoiceDtm datetime

INSERT INTO [dbo].[InvoiceItem] (invoice_item_name, amount, invoice_id)
select "Tuition", Grade.tuition_amount, invoice.invoice_id
from Student
join invoice on student.student_id = invoice.student_id
join grade on student.grade_id = grade.grade_id
where student.invoice_date = @invoiceDtm
--if you really want to specifiy the first names
and student.first_name in ('Murdoch', 'Hartwell')
```